# Make a radio button in Eclipse plugin's menu

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, action

I have this menu that has 2 items Compile and Run [shown in the screenshot below]

I want to make another menu item in the form :
[ Language-> ] and Language has other two items 'German' & 'French' that have check boxes or Radio buttons as I want the user to check one of the 2 languages and I detect that so I can make some changes according to the language check

so now I need 2 things
1- make the menu with that format and they have to be checkable
2- How to detect which one was checked

[image: Figure 1]

Here is the XML code for the menu

```
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">

      <actionSet
            id="Bachelor.actionSet"
            label="New menu"
            visible="true">

  <menu
               id="sampleMenu"
               label="Localized">
            <separator
                  name="sampleGroup">
            </separator>
            <groupMarker
                  name="content">
            </groupMarker>
         </menu>
<action
      class="bachelor.actions.Compile"
      icon="icons/sample.gif"
      id="bachelor.actions.Compile"
      label="&amp;Compile"
      menubarPath="sampleMenu/content"
      toolbarPath="sampleGroup"
      tooltip="Open the resource manager view">
</action>
<action
      class="bachelor.actions.Run"
      icon="icons/sample.gif"
      id="bachelor.actions.Run"
      label="&amp;Run"
      menubarPath="sampleMenu/content"
      toolbarPath="sampleGroup"
      tooltip="Open the resource manager view">
</action>
      </actionSet>
   </extension>



</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
style="radio"
```

to the XML definitions. See the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_actionSets.html) for more information and how to choose which of the two is marked by default.